# Parcelable Derived Class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Android Parcelable plugin from https://github.com/nekocode/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin

I tried it on a class with this definition

```
class ChessClock : TextView  {
    lateinit var player:String
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context:Context, p:String, angle:Float) : this(context) {
       player = p
       rotation = angle
   }
   <snip>
}
```

and the definition was changed to

```
class ChessClock() : TextView, Parcelable {
   lateinit var player:String 
   constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
   constructor(context:Context, p:String, angle:Float) : this(context){
       player = p
       rotation = angle
   }
   <snip -- various stuff added here>
}
```

Two syntax errors were highlighted.

In the line

```
class ChessClock() : TextView, Parcelable
```

`TextView` is underlined, with the comment "This type has a constructor, and must be initialized here."

In the line

```
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
```

`super` is underlined, with the comment "Primary constructor call expected."

I've only been using kotlin for a few weeks, and I don't understand what's going on here.  First of all, I know (or at least I think I know) that kotlin doesn't implement multiple inheritance, so I don't understand what

class ChessClock() : TextView, Parcelable

means.  Is this really legitimate kotlin?  How can one make a derived class Parcelable in kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TextView is a class and therefore your primary constructor should
   invoke one of its constructors
2. you should invoke your primary constructor from other constructors

Example:

```
class ChessClock(context: Context) : TextView(context), Parcelable

//in this case you don't need other constructors but in-case you do, this is how you should write it:
constructor(context: Context, dummy: Int): this(context)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: Oops.  I spoke too soon.  Now I see that the compiler is complaining about the declaration `constructor(parcel: Parcel) :this()`.  How should this declaration be changed?

Comment: I'm going to make this a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change the generated code from `ChessClock()` to `ChessClock`.

Comment: but that won't help you address the `constructor(parcel: Parcel)` problem, see my [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578982/constructor-taking-parcelable-constructor-in-kotlin-derived-class/45579620#45579620)... but the short answer is to not try to make your UI parcelable, separate the UI from the backing data if you can.