# Constructor Taking Parcelable Constructor in kotlin Derived Class

Tags: android, kotlin

This is a followup to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576845/parcelable-derived-class-in-kotlin) I asked earlier.  I am using the Android Parcelable plugin from https://github.com/nekocode/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin
Following bennyl's suggestion, I changed the generated code for the constructors to

```
class ChessClock(context:Context) : TextView(context), Parcelable {
    lateinit var player:String
    constructor(context:Context, p:String, angle:Float) : this(context) {
        player = p
        rotation = angle
    }
}
```

and this got rid of the syntax errors I had asked about.  I now have another problem that I overlooked at first.

The plugin generated this code for `writeToParcel`:

```
override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(player)
    parcel.writeFloat(rotation)
    parcel.writeLong(mTime)
    parcel.writeInt(mState)
}
```

and this constructor:

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) :this() {
    player = parcel.readString()
    rotation = parcel.readFloat()
    mTime = parcel.readLong()
    mState = parcel.readInt()
}
```

(Actually, I added the lines with rotation, but that's unimportant.)

Now, the constructor won't compile.  `this` is underlined and I see the tooltip
[image]
I would expect to see something like,

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) :this(context, parcel.readString(), parcel.readFloat()) {
    mTime = parcel.readLong()
    mState = parcel.readInt()
}
```

but if I try that, I get the message, "Cannot access context before superclass constructor has been called."  I'm pretty new to kotlin (and android) and I don't understand what's happening here.  I've tried invoking `super`, but it tells me that a call to the primary constructor is expected.  I've also tried invoking TextView() but it tells me that a call to `this` or `super` is expected.

I don't see that there is a way to write the context to the parcel, (and I'm not sure what this would mean.)

Can you tell me how the code should be modified, and more important, can you explain why?

Comment: `context` is not a parameter of your `constructor(parcel: Parcel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` needs to be supplied in order to call the `this(context,...)` constructors.  But, you cannot change your `constructor(parcel: Parcel)` to `constructor(context: Context, parcel: Parcel)` because Parcelable requires the `constructor(parcel: Parcel)

What's going on?  Your class derives from `TextView` which requires a `Context` to instantiate.  Your primary `constructor` is doing that...

```
class ChessClock(context: Context) : TextView(context) ...
```

The documentation says...

> If the class has a primary constructor, the base type can (and must) be initialized right there, using the parameters of the primary constructor.

Since you've chosen to use a primary constructor, the base class must be initialized by that constructor, and the secondary constructors chain off of the primary.

```
    constructor(context:Context, p:String, angle:Float) : this(context) ...
    // notice how the secondary constructor has the context with which to
    // call the primary constructor
```

The error you are seeing is due to the second secondary constructor not supplying a context to the constructor that it is calling (it's calling the first secondary constructor).

```
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) :this(context, parcel.readString(), parcel.readFloat()) ...
    // compiler error because "context" has no source, there is no 
    // parameter "context" being supplied
```

**More importantly**, the `Parcel` constructor was added by the Parcelable Plug-in tool when it added `Parcelable` Interface to the inheritance ([see the example of a Parcelable implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)).  And as such, the `CREATOR` method (the required `Parcelable.Creator` Interface) expects to find a constructor that takes only a `Parcel`.  You may have to adjust your design, because a `Context` is not serializable and therefore should not (cannot) be placed in a `Parcel`. You could look at the `CREATOR` code and see about modifying that, but I would recommend a design change.

"Best practice" is to separate your business logic from your UI logic.  Here you have tied your `ChessClock` to a UI object `TextView`.  A "ChessClock" sound to me like UI, so maybe you need a ChessClockData class to pass around as a `Parcelable` instead of the Clock UI.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I've been doing some more reading, and it seems to me that I should have been googling "saving state in custom views."  However, your suggestion of a design change is probably going to be easier to implement.  I'm going to have to save the state of the game anyway.